# Excel Pivot Table Date Filter

Tags: excel, date, filter, pivot, pivot-table

In a normal table, I can easily filter the Date Column and specify multiple criteria. Example Data is after X **AND** is after Y.

How can I do this in a Pivot Table?
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kwrJ.png)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't supported. Here is a workaround. Create a column in your source data which duplicates the date data exactly, for example, date1 and date2. Then you can apply one filter to each field.

Comment: Thanks! This could do.